# Best way to handle api callbacks in wordpos library?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new handling promises in javascript and I've found a problem with this node js lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpos I'm trying to find all the verbs that are found inside an arrays of strings, and for this I've created this function:

```
function calculateVerbsAmount(stringsArray) {
return stringsArray.map(function(item) { 
    let element = wordpos.getVerbs(item, function(result){
        return result;
    });    
});
```

}

What I expect is to have a new array, this time of verb strings, but since the lib handles the methods as callbacks I'm getting

```
[Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> },
Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> },
Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> }]
```

I've tried added async/await but they always return the same result, any idea on how to do some synchronous call to the wordpos.getVerbs method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `wordpos.getVerbs()` returns a `promise`. Since you are doing this inside a `.map` function your `stringsArray` will be an array of promises (as you actually get as return.).

A single `Promise` can be unwraped using `await`. For an array of `Promises` you can use `Promise.all` helper which allows waiting for each `Promise` within an `array`.

##### Example

```js
async function calculateVerbsAmount(stringsArray) {
    const verbPromises = stringsArray.map(function(item) { 
        let element = wordpos.getVerbs(item, function(result){
            return result;
        });    
    });

    // await every Promise within the verbPromises array. Promise.all
    // returns a single Promise which holds an array with the native values
    return Promise.all(verbPromises)
}


// the keyword "await" can only be used within an async function. 
// So for showcasing it i created the main() function ..
async function main() {
    
    // Now call the calculateVerbsAmount() and await it for receiving the expected
    // array of strings. 
    const verbs = await calculateVerbsAmount()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! after some adjustements to my code it works as I was expecting :)